# How to design a simple to parse reliable text based protocol

Tags: protocols, communication, data-transfer

I need to design a text based protocol between two devices where at least one is not a PC.
So I can't rely on libraries, regular expressions and other fancy tools.
The languages typically offer little more than what `BASIC` (if, loops, toString, fromString, fixed sized strings) could offer.

The messages are transmitted via TCP/IP. Text encoding is ASCII.

The protocol shall allow sending messages at any time (one partner may send 5 messages in a row).

The issues I figured out so far:

1. I need a way to split the stream of characters into possibly several messages.
2. Since some fields in a message can be of varying length I need a way to split a message into fields as well.
3. I need to support several message types which I'd like to solve by sending a message type field as the very first field in each message.

My plan so far:

- Introduce a message delimiter like '\0' to cope with 1.
- Introduce a field delimiter like '\t' to cope with 2.
- Send a protocol type as text or integer as first field.

Sample:

```
42\t123.456\tsome string\t4\042\t12.456\tsome other string\t5\0
```

Shall be interpreted as:

```
[42 , 123.456 , "some string" , 4], [42 , 12.456 , "some other string" , 5]
```

Problems I see:

- How to deal with "escaping" the delimiters, i.e. strings that contain '\t' or '\0'?
  Disallow the delimiters (maybe choose some from characters 128+)?

What do you think of this protocol? Are there good alternatives? Remember, the programming facilites are quite limited!